# Fast formula for gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am trying to find an efficient way of evaluating the gamma function gamma(t) where t is a complex number.  The Wolfram Mathworld page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html gives a number of formulas involving infinite series and infinite products, but it does not appear to have any information on rates of convergence.

Comment: Do you need the analytic continuation? The integral converges fairly quickly where it converges at all.

Comment: @Ian: yes, I am assuming t is any complex number other than the negative integers and 0